# How to debug a python script that is executed by crontab?

Tags: python, linux, cron

Currently I have a python script that has the following structure

```
read_data()
    print("debugging statement 1")
    # random code 

plot_data(data)
    print("debugging statement 2")
    #random code 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   var = "test1"
   var2 = "test2"
   data_organized = read_data(var,var2)
   print("debugging statement 3")
   plot_data(data_organized)

   .....rest of code .....
```

I ssh into a raspberry pi and from the terminal I can write:

```
/full/path/to/env/python3 /full/path/to/script.py
```

and the script executes perfectly no errors at all.

I placed it in a crontab to run every minute with the following crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /full/path/to/env/bin/python3 /full/path/to/script/script.py >> /random/path/to/where/i/want/output/cron_log.txt 2>&1
```

but the python code throws out an error. when I check my cron_log.txt file I see the error occurred somewhere in the read_data() function because I can see that the print("debugging statement 3) output is off from what it should be. But I cannot see any of the print statements that are inside of the read_data() function.

questions:

1.) why would the code run perfectly when I directly run it but when I run it with crontab it throws out an error?

2.) is my crontab entry correct? I want it to run every minute

3.) how can I write the ouput of the print() functions within the read_data(), plot_Data() functions? currently I can only see print(debugging3) in my output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. because cron jobs run in a very different environment compared to your terminal. most likely cron jobs are executed with the different permissions and from a different folder, also you cannot rely on PATH variable being the same (or any other variable for that matter)
2. that seems ok.
3. your script is breaking in `read_data()`, once you fix this you'll see your debugging output

Finally, why it does not work and how to fix it. Since you haven't provided any meaningful sources, I'd say your `read_data()` function tries to access some data files using relative paths and fails, since the script is executed from a different folder. You should make sure all paths are absolute and the permissions are set to allow access to those files.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this in another script which will call your `script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# You can name me: logger.py
import subprocess
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
    subprocess.call(["python", "./script.py"], stdout=output);
```

Comment: so are you saying to create this new file and execute the new one in the crontab? from my understanding is that this new file just runs my old script and does something with the logging. is there a way to fix the logging directly in my script and not have to create a whole new file?

Comment: You can just try this approach to get the full log, in order to debug later and see where your code really fails (something you can't do right now because the log is not being saved correctly).

Once you detect the error, you will no longer need this previous script.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the error is a permissions issue. (see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/what-are-the-runtime-permissions-of-a-cron-job )

To debug the process, you *could* use a tool like [remote_pdb](https://pypi.org/project/remote-pdb/) and then step through your script.